# Java mobile: Android or Blackberry?

Tags: java, android, blackberry

Most of the questions on SO has been too generic, comparing iPhone, Android and Blackberry all at once. I want to ask your experience between developing on Android and Blackberry.

From your experience as Java programmer:

- Which platform do you enjoy developing on the most?
- Which API do you find is well written and fun to code?
- Which development platform that is fun to work with?
- Which platform do you find most stable and less issues with?

Android or Blackberry? Any other noteworthy checklists to share to Java programmers that want to choose whether to develop on Android or Blackberry?

Thank you for sharing your experience with us here.

Comment: I can't speak to most of that but I will say that Java on Android is a lot closer to standard Java than BlackBerry is.

Comment: @jpartogi: it is obviously Android.  I've been developing mobile apps on Java cellphones and smartphones (including RIM's "berries") "back in the days" and it was **extremely** painful.  Google has decided to solve a *lot* of the issues developers had when trying to target mobile devices and apparently it is working.  In addition to that Android sales are skyrocketing and that technology (backed by the $300bn+ market cap company that Google is) is here to stay.  Go for Android and don't look back.

Comment: @Webinator: How come the market growth for Android is not as rapid as Blackberry?

Comment: @jpartogi not sure what stats you are looking at, but those I have seen show BB market share shrinking while iPhone is growing and Android growing even more.
Platform-wise it's really no contest. BB Java is basically J2ME plus some BB-specific APIs. Android is standard Java plus Android-specific APIs. Android's tools and platform are just a world better.

Comment: @Sean: Thanks for sharing me the info. I might consider Android if it is really that good and if the market is really growing.

Comment: @jpartogi: Absolutely agree with Webinator.  Android's documentation, tools, guides and video tutorials at http://developer.android.com are fantastic.  The APIs make sense, the community is there and active, the hardware solid and fun, the Maps API is ridiculously easy to get the hang of, it really does feel like straight up Java...

Another vote for Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Android**, I don't have much expertise on the BB SDK, but AFAIK, the Android community is much wide and diverse than BB community.

Advantages of Android:

1. Backed by Google
2. Huge community
3. Linux
4. More Open than BB
5. Many more.....

Here is a blog post which answers your question to some extent: [Android development vs. Blackberry Development](http://www.inteism.com/2009/04/android-development-vs-blackberry-development/)

Comment: Thanks. The link was definitely useful.